# Geforce 4060 or 3060 (Ti) for Blender PC Build

Tags: graphics-cards

Hellooo!

I am going to build my first Blender PC. I have been working on a Macbook Pro (2016) for many years so I am not very up to date with PC components.

I have a budget of €1000. So far I have come up with the next build:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 7600
- GPU: INNO3D Geforce RTX 4060 Twin X2 OC White
- Motherboard: ASUS TUF Gaming B650M-PLUS Wifi (I like to have
  bluetooth and wifi)
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 32 GB DDR5
- Power supply:
  be quiet! System Power 10 550W
- SSD: Samsung 980 1 TB
- Processor
  cooler: NZXT T120 CPU Cooler
- Casing: Fractal Design Pop Silent

My question:
I was initially looking at a Geforce 3060 or a 3060Ti, but if I believe the blender benchmarks the 4060 performance is better. The 4060 only has 8GB compared to the 12GB of the 3060, will that be a problem? Because I also read that some people are not that happy with the 4060 but that is mainly when it comes to gaming, so not sure about Blender use.

Answer (score 1):

So I have looked at some benchmarks from Tweakers, and from there I conclude that if you don't need the extra vram for your specific projects the 4060 is about 18% faster while using about 30% less power than the 3060 12GB. If the workload you have however requires between 8 and 12GB VRAM, the 3060 will be way faster because between that range the 3060 doesn't have to swap to system memory while the 4060 does. I cannot say however VRAM you will need, that depends per project (I have seen one on LTT that could use more than 50GB VRAM, while there are ones that can be done on less than 4GB)

Comment: Were those benchmarks measuring game FPS or some benchmarks specific to Blender? Linking your source would improve the answer.

Comment: Those were in game since I don't have any blender specific benchmarks